# Can it be correct to have a bracket as its own sentence?

Tags: word-usage, parentheses

Is it correct English to have a sentence, and then a bracketed sentence as its own sentence? If you don't get what I mean, here's an example:

> The garden set on fire. (Even the fence set on fire). blah blah blah....

(sorry - can't think of a good example right now!)

I sometimes want to write a bracket on its own, and sometimes see it done, but it doesn't seem right to me - is it?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with putting an entire sentence in brackets, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Why the doubt? (Whence, why the question?)

Comment: I see it as a NARQ. Also, this could be expressed in one line: "Is a sentence in parentheses valid?"

Comment: @Kris It just doesn't seem right because normally brackets are used for adding information to a previous statement, so does that mean if it is its own sentence, it doesn't necessarily have to make sense on its own?

Comment: Why would it not have to make sense on its own? See my previous comment. (One sentence, and another in parentheses.)

Comment: The period (full stop) should be inside the parens, if it's a parenthetical sentence (which is otherwise perfectly valid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My native English speaking brethren are more qualified than me to answer this question.I myself do not see anything wrong with using a [sentence in parenthesis](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=514771) as a separate sentence.Example: "I saw a car accident yesterday. (It was horrible)."

I have seen it used by others in other languages.I use it myself in my language as a literary device.

Comment: As I said above, it should be "(It was horrible.)".

Comment: But I am not sure why you would put that particular sentence in parenthesis. Usually it is where the words in parenthesis are incidental to the main point. For example *My wife and I were dining at a restaurant last night. (It was her birthday.)As we were being served with the main course there was a loud explosion in the next room.*

Comment: -1 because the principle is *the brackets **and everything contained within them*** should be able to be removed without affecting the grammaticality of the text remaining. Therefore in your example the period must go ***inside*** the brackets.

Comment: My native English speaking brethren are more qualified than I to answer this question. My native English speaking brethren are more qualified than I am qualified to answer this question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Blessed Geek Noted! Thank you for teaching me---I learned something new.As the Arabic saying goes "whoever taught me even a single letter I am grateful to them forever."